# Terminal Custom Message Mistake

Tags: gnome-terminal

I placed a custom message in the GNOME Terminal to see if it worked.  Now every time I try to open it, the terminal closes automatically. I know I put the option to display the message and then close itself, but now I can't undo it. I tried uninstalling and downloading it again but that did not work.

Comment: How exactly did you "place" it into gnome-terminal ? Which file or setting did you edit  ?

Comment: If you did it through gnome-terminal profile settings, try deleting everything in `.gconf/apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/` folder (notice leading dot in `.gnome` , which makes it a hidden folder), and then try opening gnome-terminal. This should remove all profiles and start with default profile. Let me know if that works, and I'll convert my comment to an answer

Comment: i did it through profile settings, i found .gconf/apps/ but there is no gnome-terminal folder or file in there

Comment: Ok, in that case, do you have any other profile there ? You could try opening the terminal, then switch to another profile and click relaunch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install `dconf Editor`, because I think, a GUI is a good choice here:

```
 sudo apt-get install dconf-editor
```

Open the application with:

```
 dconf-editor
```

and open this path in the tree:

```
org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Settings
```

Open the profiles as shown in the screenshot:

[image]

and revert your changes...